# Error: System.Windows.Style' is not a valid value for property 'ContextMenu'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, contextmenu

I am trying to use a context menu and I get the following error as soon as I press the right mouse button:

System.Windows.Style' is not a valid value for property 'ContextMenu'.

XAML code:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="SharedInstanceContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding Path=EditSelectedItemCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>

        <Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource SharedInstanceContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    ...

    <ListView ...
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}"/>
```

(I used dots to remove unrelated code).

Does anybody know how to prevent the error (and seeing a context menu)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}"/>
```

`MyItemContainerStyle` is a `Style`, not a `ContextMenu`... you should probably write this instead:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource SharedInstanceContextMenu}"/>
```

Comment: It seems to work ... however it does not fire the command (I could remove the double setter btw). Or is this another question I should ask separately?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, yes, ask a separate question, it will be easier to answer than in the comments...